# How to plot a contour line showing where 95% of values fall within, in R and in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Say we have:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)
```

How do I use ggplot2 to produce a plot containing the two following geoms:

1. The bivariate expectation of the two series of values
2. A contour line showing where 95% of the estimates fall within?

I know how to do the first part:

```
 df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
 p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))
 p <- p + xlim(-10, 10) + ylim(-10, 10) # say
 p <- p + geom_point(x=mean(x), y=mean(y))
```

And I also know about the stat_contour() and stat_density2d() functions within ggplot2.

And I  also know that there are 'bins' options within stat_contour.

However, I guess what I need is something like the probs argument within quantile, but over two dimensions rather than one.

I have also seen a solution within the graphics package. However, I would like to do this within ggplot.

Help much appreciated,

Jon

Comment: isn't `stat_density2d` exactly what you need for part 1?  For part 2 (contour line enclosing 95% of the probability), I can show you how to determine the relevant cutoff density outside of ggplot2, and then use that density to specify the contour lines, but I don't think it can all be done within ggplot2 without some extreme wizardry (i.e. writing your own stat/geom components)

Comment: Sadly not. That seems to show bounds of y ~ x. I'm after a smoothed polygon on the x-y plane demarcating the region in which 95% of the scatter (or density based on the scatter) lie. Thanks though.

Comment: I mean I want to summarise a lot of bivariate values by a point showing the centre of the distribution (part 1), and a single contour line showing where the estimates are concentrated within. i.e. to do graphically over two dimensions something similar to what quantile (x, probs=c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975)) does over one dimension.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I know about the following when using graphics package alone, which sort-of works, but was hoping there would be an option to do this kind of thing simply within ggplot2 as well, as the default aesthetics are nicer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer currently fails with `Error: Unknown parameters: breaks` on `ggplot2 2.1.0`. I cobbled together an alternative approach based on the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954207/1826241), which uses the `ks` package for computing the kernel density estimate:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1001)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))

kd <- ks::kde(d, compute.cont=TRUE)
contour_95 <- with(kd, contourLines(x=eval.points[[1]], y=eval.points[[2]],
                                    z=estimate, levels=cont["5%"])[[1]])
contour_95 <- data.frame(contour_95)

ggplot(data=d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(aes(x, y), data=contour_95) +
  theme_bw()
```

Here's the result:

[image]

**TIP**: The `ks` package depends on the `rgl` package, which can be a pain to compile manually. Even if you're on Linux, it's much easier to get a precompiled version, e.g. `sudo apt install r-cran-rgl` on Ubuntu if you have the appropriate CRAN repositories set up.

Answer (score 10):

Riffing off of Ben Bolker's answer, a solution that can handle multiple levels and works with ggplot 2.2.1:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(reshape2)
# create data:
set.seed(8675309)
Sigma <- matrix(c(0.1,0.3,0.3,4),2,2)
mv <- data.frame(mvrnorm(4000,c(1.5,16),Sigma))

# get the kde2d information: 
mv.kde <- kde2d(mv[,1], mv[,2], n = 400)
dx <- diff(mv.kde$x[1:2])  # lifted from emdbook::HPDregionplot()
dy <- diff(mv.kde$y[1:2])
sz <- sort(mv.kde$z)
c1 <- cumsum(sz) * dx * dy

# specify desired contour levels:
prob <- c(0.95,0.90,0.5)

# plot:
dimnames(mv.kde$z) <- list(mv.kde$x,mv.kde$y)
dc <- melt(mv.kde$z)
dc$prob <- approx(sz,1-c1,dc$value)$y
p <- ggplot(dc,aes(x=Var1,y=Var2))+
  geom_contour(aes(z=prob,color=..level..),breaks=prob)+
  geom_point(aes(x=X1,y=X2),data=mv,alpha=0.1,size=1)
print(p)
```

The result:

[image: joint contour plot]

Answer (score 9):

This works, but is quite inefficient because you actually have to compute the kernel density estimate three times.

```
set.seed(1001)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
getLevel <- function(x,y,prob=0.95) {
    kk <- MASS::kde2d(x,y)
    dx <- diff(kk$x[1:2])
    dy <- diff(kk$y[1:2])
    sz <- sort(kk$z)
    c1 <- cumsum(sz) * dx * dy
    approx(c1, sz, xout = 1 - prob)$y
}
L95 <- getLevel(d$x,d$y)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) +
   stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..),
                  contour = FALSE)+
   stat_density2d(colour="red",breaks=L95)
```

(with help from http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.ggplot2/303)

**update**: with a recent version of `ggplot2` (2.1.0) it doesn't seem possible to pass `breaks` to `stat_density2d` (or at least I don't know how), but the method below with `geom_contour` still seems to work ...

You can make things a little more efficient by computing the kernel density estimate once and plotting the tiles and contours from the same grid:

```
kk <- with(dd,MASS::kde2d(x,y))
library(reshape2)
dimnames(kk$z) <- list(kk$x,kk$y)
dc <- melt(kk$z)
ggplot(dc,aes(x=Var1,y=Var2))+
   geom_tile(aes(fill=value))+
   geom_contour(aes(z=value),breaks=L95,colour="red")
```

- doing the 95% level computation from the `kk` grid (to reduce the number of kernel computations to 1) is left as an exercise
- I'm not sure why `stat_density2d(geom="tile")` and `geom_tile` give slightly different results (the former is smoothed)
- I haven't added the bivariate mean, but something like `annotate("point",x=mean(d$x),y=mean(d$y),colour="red")` should work.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Very good and something I'm sure I'll use many times. 
Inefficiency's relative as of course anything that works is much more efficient than anything that's not!

Comment: Nice solution, thanks very much -- I was looking for something like this as well. Note that while the contour line this generates will encompass 95% of the probability density, it will in practice encompass more than 95% of the actual observations in most cases.

Comment: FYI, this (the first example) currently raises an error (`Error: Unknown parameters: breaks`) on `ggplot2 2.1.0`. Would you perhaps know how to adapt the code to make it work again? It seems really useful!

Comment: don't know, sorry.  Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: I cobbled something together using the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25954207/1826241), I'll post it as an alternate solution :) Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 4):

I had an example where the `MASS::kde2d()` bandwidth specifications were not flexible enough, so I ended up using the `ks` package and the `ks::kde()` function and, as an example, the `ks::Hscv()` function to estimate flexible bandwidths that captured the smoothness better. This computation can be a bit slow, but it has much better performance in some situations. Here is a version of the above code for that example:

```
set.seed(1001)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
getLevel <- function(x,y,prob=0.95) {
    kk <- MASS::kde2d(x,y)
    dx <- diff(kk$x[1:2])
    dy <- diff(kk$y[1:2])
    sz <- sort(kk$z)
    c1 <- cumsum(sz) * dx * dy
    approx(c1, sz, xout = 1 - prob)$y
}
L95 <- getLevel(d$x,d$y)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) +
    stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..),
                   contour = FALSE)+
    stat_density2d(colour="red",breaks=L95)

## using ks::kde
hscv1 <- Hscv(d)
fhat <- ks::kde(d, H=hscv1, compute.cont=TRUE)

dimnames(fhat[['estimate']]) <- list(fhat[["eval.points"]][[1]], 
                                     fhat[["eval.points"]][[2]])
library(reshape2)
aa <- melt(fhat[['estimate']])

ggplot(aa, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) +
    geom_contour(aes(z=value), breaks=fhat[["cont"]]["50%"], color="red") +
    geom_contour(aes(z=value), breaks=fhat[["cont"]]["5%"], color="purple")
```

For this particular example, the differences are minimal, but in an example where the bandwidth specification requires more flexibility, this modification may be important. Note that the 95% contour is specified using the `breaks=fhat[["cont"]]["5%"]`, which I found a little bit counter-intuitive, because it is called here the "5% contour".

Answer (score 2):

Just mixing answers from above, putting them in a more `tidyverse` friendly way, and allowing for multiple contour levels. I use here `geom_path(group=probs)`, adding them manually `geom_text`. Another approach is to use `geom_path(colour=probs)` which will automatically label the contours as legend.

```r
library(ks)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1001)

## data
d <- MASS::mvrnorm(1000, c(0, 0.2), matrix(c(1, 0.4, 1, 0.4), ncol=2)) %>% 
  magrittr::set_colnames(c("x", "y")) %>% 
  as_tibble() 

## density function
kd <- ks::kde(d, compute.cont=TRUE, h=0.2)

## extract results
get_contour <- function(kd_out=kd, prob="5%") {
  contour_95 <- with(kd_out, contourLines(x=eval.points[[1]], y=eval.points[[2]],
                                      z=estimate, levels=cont[prob])[[1]])
  as_tibble(contour_95) %>% 
    mutate(prob = prob)
}

dat_out <- map_dfr(c("10%", "20%","80%", "90%"), ~get_contour(kd, .)) %>% 
  group_by(prob) %>% 
  mutate(n_val = 1:n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

## clean kde output
kd_df <- expand_grid(x=kd$eval.points[[1]], y=kd$eval.points[[2]]) %>% 
  mutate(z = c(kd$estimate %>% t))

ggplot(data=kd_df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) +
  geom_point(data = d, alpha = I(0.4), size = I(0.4), colour = I("yellow")) +
  geom_path(aes(x, y, group = prob), 
            data=filter(dat_out, !n_val %in% 1:3), colour = I("white")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = prob), data = 
              filter(dat_out, (prob%in% c("10%", "20%","80%") & n_val==1) | (prob%in% c("90%") & n_val==20)),
            colour = I("black"), size =I(3))+
  scale_fill_viridis_c()+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>