# geom_statdensity2d with specific contours?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to be able to use the `geom_density2d()` geom to draw contour levels on a scatter plot at user defined locations. Consider the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
n = 100
df = data.frame(x = c(rnorm(n, 0, .5), rnorm(n, 3, .5)),
                y = c(rnorm(n, 1, .5), rnorm(n, 0, .5)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
   geom_density2d() +
   geom_point()
```

[image]

This produces a standard contour plot but there doesn't appear to be a way to manually control which contours get drawn. The optional parameters bins and h in can control the contour lines to some degree (being passed to kde2d from MASS I assume) but the resulting lines do not seem to be interpretable.

Ideally, I would be able to replicate the functionality of plot.kde from the ks library where these can be controlled via that cont argument.

```
library(ks)
est = kde(df)
plot(est, cont = c(50, 95))
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437000/how-to-plot-a-contour-line-showing-where-95-of-values-fall-within-in-r-and-in

Answer (score 0):

This is my naive attempt since I hardly write custom functions. So the following may not be a good approach. At least, the code does the job, though. My trick is to use a data set that ggplot created. First, you draw a graphic and get the data used for the graphic, which you can find from `ggplot_build(g)$data[1]`. In this, you can find a column called `level`. Using the column, you can subset data for each contour line. In `myfun()`, you need to specify which levels you want. The function subsets the data with the specified levels and draw a figure.

```
setseed(111)
mydf = data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, 0, .5), rnorm(100, 3, .5)),
                  y = c(rnorm(100, 1, .5), rnorm(100, 0, .5)))

g <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
            geom_density2d() +
            geom_point()

### Get a list containing data used for drawing g.

temp <- as.data.frame(ggplot_build(g)$data[1])

### Check which levels you have in g

ind <- unique(temp$level)

ind
#[1] 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.10 0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.20


myfun <- function(...){
               ana <- c(...)
               foo <- subset(temp, level %in% ana)

               g <- ggplot() +
               geom_path(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group), colour = "red")

               print(g)

               }

### Run myfun by specify levels you want.
myfun(0.02, 0.10, 0.18)
```

[image]