# How to find outer limits of contour lines for three-dimensional data in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, kernel-density

I would like to extend the example given here

[How to plot a contour line showing where 95% of values fall within, in R and in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437000/how-to-plot-a-contour-line-showing-where-95-of-values-fall-within-in-r-and-in)

to data with three dimensions (x, y and z), and instead of plotting the contour line I'd like to get the limits of the x, y and z values.

This is the example from the previous post.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1001)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))

kd <- ks::kde(d, compute.cont=TRUE)
contour_95 <- with(kd, contourLines(x=eval.points[[1]], y=eval.points[[2]],
                                    z=estimate, levels=cont["5%"])[[1]])
contour_95 <- data.frame(contour_95)

ggplot(data=d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(aes(x, y), data=contour_95) +
  theme_bw()
```

and then, it's possible to get the limits of the contour like this:

```
range(contour_95$x)
range(contour_95$y)
```

I would love to know how to get the x, y and z ranges of 3-D contours at specified percentiles.

ks:kde can deal with higher dimensions, but contourLines() cant.

This is what I've tried...

```
set.seed(1001)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000))
kd <- ks::kde(d, compute.cont=TRUE)
#what kd$estimates are > 95th percentile?

#make function that can extract from 3d array
multi.which <- function(A){
  if ( is.vector(A) ) return(which(A))
  d <- dim(A)
  T <- which(A) - 1
  nd <- length(d)
  t( sapply(T, function(t){
    I <- integer(nd)
    I[1] <- t %% d[1]
    sapply(2:nd, function(j){
      I[j] <<- (t %/% prod(d[1:(j-1)])) %% d[j]
    })
    I
  }) + 1 )
}

#extract those estimates that have >density than 95th percentile
ests <- multi.which(kd$estimate > kd$cont["5%"])

#make into a long dataframe with column number in the second column and row number in first column
col1=rep(1, nrow(ests))
col2=rep(2, nrow(ests))
col3=rep(3, nrow(ests))
rows=c(ests[,1], ests[,2], ests[,3])
cols=c(col1,col2,col3)
index=cbind(rows,cols)#this is the index so we can extract the coordinates in multi-D space
car::some(index)

#get coordinates with this function
fExtract <- function(dat, indexDat){
  dat[as.matrix(indexDat)]
}

#pull three coordinates (x,y,z) from eval.points into 3 columns 
eval.pts <- cbind(kd$eval.points[[1]], kd$eval.points[[2]], kd$eval.points[[3]])

v <- fExtract(eval.pts, index) #one long vector

#re-create the three columns of x, y and z coordinates of points at higher density than 95th percentile
x1 <- v[1:nrow(ests)]
y1 <- v[(nrow(ests)+1):(2*nrow(ests))]
z1 <- v[(2*nrow(ests)+1):(3*nrow(ests))]

#the three coordinates.
fin <- cbind(x1,y1,z1)

#get range of each dimension
range(x1)
range(y1)
range(z1)
```

But I'm not confident it's right.

Comment: What have you tried? From the help file, `ks::kde` works on 1-6 dimensions

Comment: Yes, ks::kde works on more dimensions, but contourLines() doesn't.